# compare dictionaries

Tags: c#

i have 3 generic dictionaries

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> input = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    input.Add("KEY1", "Key1");

    Dictionary<string, string> compare = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    compare.Add("KEY1", "Key1");
    compare.Add("KEY2", "Key2");
    compare.Add("KEY3", "Key3");

    Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

i'd like to take the list of input and compare each value to the compareTo list and if it doesn't exist add it to the results list?

Comment: to clarify, you want all members in `compare` not in `input`?  Or all members of `input` not in `compare`?  I assumed the former, but if the latter just reverse the operands in my answer.

Comment: The question is a little ambiguous.  You want to compare each value to the `compare` list, but what is a value?  Do you mean if one of the `string` items in `input.Values` is present in `compare.Values`, or if one of the `KeyValuePair<string, string>` items in `input` is present in `compare`?  Or are you just looking at the keys, as one might expect in code that uses a dictionary?

Comment: @phoog: I'm assuming from his "compare each value" in the question that he wants any value (for a given key) that is different or non-existent to be in results.  Is that correct rod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LINQ Except() method:

```
        foreach (var pair in compare.Except(input))
        {
            results[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
        }
```

This will perform a set difference (in effect subtracting `input` from `compare` and returning what is left over), which we can then add to the `results` dictionary.

Now, if `results` has no previous values, and you just want it to be the `results` from that current operation, you can just do that directly:

```
      var results = compare.Except(input)
                           .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

This is assuming you want the difference in keys **and** values.  If you had a different value (same key), it would show in the difference.

That is, for your example above results will have:

```
[KEY2, Key2]
[KEY3, Key3]
```

But if your example data was:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> input = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        input.Add("KEY1", "Key1");

        Dictionary<string, string> compare = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        compare.Add("KEY1", "X");
        compare.Add("KEY2", "Key2");
        compare.Add("KEY3", "Key3");
```

The results would be:

```
[KEY1, X]
[KEY2, Key2]
[KEY3, Key3]
```

Due to the fact KEY1's value was different.

If you do want only where keys or values are not contained in the other, you can do the `Except` on the `Keys` or `Values` collections of the dictionary instead.

Comment: I think you got it backwards. It's `input.Except(compare)` if I understood correctly.

Comment: @Cicada: I think he wants all elements in `compare` not in `input` the way I read it.  If he wants the opposite obviously he'd just reverse the operands.

Answer (score 1):

`dict[key]` gives you the value whose key is `key`.

`dict.ContainsKey(key)` and `dict.ContainsValue(value)` are methods you can use to check whether a key or a value are in the dictionary. `ContainsKey` is more time-efficient.